# Making a game where people battle robots by compiling them into dlls, how do I set up the groundwork?

Tags: c#, reflection

In order to stop this being subjective, I have a couple of specific questions about how to do this. First of all, I have put my guess as to the best way to do it. My primary language is C#.

I am looking more for brief information to start me off (eg, check out X, use method Y) rather than some full blown solution.

---

I'll have some kind of server application that loads in 2 compiled libraries, robot1.dll and robot2.dll which are created externally.

I'll set up the server creating two robot instances, putting them into the arena and having them battle. I'll first call a Setup() method passing an interface such as IRobot (no pun intended) like this:

```
interface IRobot
{
   ScanResult Scan();
   void MoveForwards();
   void MoveBackwards();
   void ShootGun();
}
```

And then simply call DoStuff() on both of dlls on a timer. Then the internal logic of each will callback the methods, essentially via reflection, to operate the robots.

The robot dlls would basically include RobotLibrary.dll which would contain the IRobot interface, as well as perhaps a Robot base class. Then to create a robot, they simply do

`public class MyRobot : Robot`

and hit the auto-create:

```
public class MyRobot : Robot
{
  private IRobot _robot;
  public void Setup(IRobot Robot)
  {
    this._robot = Robot;
  }

  public void DoStuff()
  {
    this._robot.MoveForwards();
  }
}
```

---

My questions:

- Is it best to use an interface to call server methods, or should I do it in reverse where a robot simply has a `Command DoStuff()` method which returns a Command that is parsed into an instruction? Is there a further, better way?
- I want to make it very easy for people to write a robot. Is importing the library, and creating a class that implements IRobot or Robot abstract class simple enough, or is there a better way?
- Will it be possible to make it interoperable between different languages? If someone produces a .dll written in a different programming language (eg. C++) would it still work?
- Would people be able to cheat or hack the system using this method, and if so how might I stop them? Not just hacking the game, but even compromising the server/system too. I don't want people to write stuff that scans the OS or installs a virus etc.
- Bonus question, is it possible to time method calls so that the more complex stuff your robot does, the slower the server processes the commands?

Comment: So the way to defeat the robots is to compile them into dlls?

Comment: They will fight each other by executing commands on the server to move them.

Comment: Please leave a comment if you're voting to close, I'd like to know how I can rephrase this, other than asking 6 individual questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to look at plugin frameworks for .NET and how they operate. The usual thing would be for somebody writing a robot to provide a DLL which exports (in some way dependent on the plugin framework) an object implementing an interface that's provided by your code. Your code then talks to that interface in order to tell the robot about the environment and find out what the robot is doing.

Multiple language support is fine as far as .NET compatibility extends - that is, if your core is in C# it's going to be easy to pull in anything that's written in any .NET language which is capable of implementing the plugin interface in the right way. So yes they could use C++ provided they use C++/CLI. They could also use Clojure/CLR, Niecza, Nemerle etc.

If you want to make it as compatible as possible with as many things as possible you need to support C libraries as plugins - C is like the base level of inter-language compatibility, and there are many, many languages which can present a C-like interface to the world. Although sometimes you have to jump through some horrible hoops to make it work.

As for security, in the basic form you're looking at free code in the DLL, so it can do absolutely anything within the permissions granted by the operating system (assuming the presence of security bugs in the OS, that means anything at all). Sandboxing the robot DLLs is a nice idea but not trivial to achieve. It may be possible to tap into .NET/Silverlight's sandboxing system if you're lucky.

A completely different idea is to define the robot<->engine protocol as a network protocol, so that robots connect to the core server and communicate using some simple wire protocol. This would remove language compatibility issues - you could write it in anything that can handle the network connections - and you could run it on a different machine, or maybe in a VM on the same machine which gives you a form of sandboxing if security is a concern as then it could only trash the VM.

A variant on that which I saw with a robot battle system years back is to write each robot as an executable which communicates via stdin and stdout with the parent process, which is responsible for launching it and attaching pipes to the child process so that they can communicate.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I'll look into the sandboxing thing as I think that's the primary concern

Answer (score 1):

Answers in the same order as questions:

1. I will prefer DoStuff returning a command (or series of commands) rather than working with `IRobot` interface. IMO, its simple to understand as opposed to having another interface that lists possible command!
2. Yes, providing an abstract implementation will do so that authors has to write only the logic that they supposed to write w/o worrying about any plumbing/infrastructure code. However, writing robots in non-.NET language would be still difficult unless you can provide wrapper robot implementations (see next item for more).
3. It will be interoperable in any .NET compatible language (and they are quite a few). For rest, you might want to consider building wrapper robots that can do duplex communication on say named pipes, TCP/IP sockets, std in/out etc. Communication protocol can be very simple, wrapper invoking PING with actual robot replying with the command. For example, a wrapper robot invoking the actual robot executable and pinging over std-in and getting commands out of std-out. Or by issuing HTTP request to an URL and getting command as response - this will allow you even creating remote robots.
4. You need to do sand-boxing i.e. load robots in to different AppDomain and apply your security policy on the app-domain. If you go for Remote robots then this question becomes mute.
5. Ideally, you need to allow only certain time-slice for robot to do something (and sand-boxing threading API). You can have total allowed time for X moves kinda of stuff!

Comment: Great, thanks. I think some kind of tcp/ip solution might be much cooler =)